# How to change kendo error messages?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

How to change kendo error messages?. My model is

```
  UIHint("Time")]
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "* required")]
       public DateTime SchoolEndTime { get; set; }
```

I want to change error message 'The field SchoolStartTime must be a date." but i want to change into 'Invalid Time'

Comment: Where is your `SchoolStartTime` which you want to change?

Comment: SchoolEndTime  is a field and its in the grid but when i type wrong date it says 'The field SchoolStartTime must be a date' but i want my own error message

Answer (score 1):

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "* required")]
 [Display(Name = "School End Time  ")]
       public DateTime SchoolEndTime { get; set; }
```

Display attribute changes error message as "School End Time must be a date" instead of "SchoolEndTime must be a date"

or

You can change validator settings

```
<span id="createdValidator">
   //grid code 
    <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="Created"></span>
</span>

$("#createdValidator").kendoValidator({
 messages: {
    date: "Invalid time. Use: mm/dd/yyyy"  //Here is your message 
 }
});
```